# Importing SAS cport file in R

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to figure out a way of importing a SAS cport file in R from some analysis. Can someone please help me as to how can I get that done? I dont want to use SAS to convert that into a csv first and then importing into R.

I tried to google it but was unable to find a proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: See the R manual http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#EpiInfo-Minitab-SAS-S_002dPLUS-SPSS-Stata-Systat and a discussion at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Read-SAS-data-td1690992.html. You may have to create a SAS xport file instead.

Comment: If you're open to using a regular SAS dataset rather than one from `cport`, i.e. a .sas7bdat file, you can try the [R package sas7bdat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/index.html).

Comment: I have the same problem. Is CPORT a newer format? What about SAS free viewer?

Comment: I believe you may have to extract the CPORT file into the individual datasets first. After that, I have very good experiences with using the `haven` R package for reading .sas7bdat or .xpt files.