# Convert SAS CPORT file to CSV without SAS

Tags: csv, sas, data-conversion

So I have SAS CPORT file that I want to convert to CSV without having SAS.

Now believe that the CPORT file version is the older version to SAS's new XPORT file. I have found tools to convert XPORT files to CSV but not for the older CPORT format.

Apparently SAS's universal translator can do it, but that won't install for some reason.

A free tool/code would be great, but happy to pay small amount (less than $150)

Cheers,
Leigh

Comment: What's your use case? Are you a researcher or student? Stat/Transfer is a legal tool that may fit your budget. If you're a student or researcher you can use SAS for free, search SAS UE and you can install it on your desktop or AWS.

Comment: @Reeza we are a government agency without SAS, being supplied with a SAS dataset. Stat/Transfer might be the way to go. I’ll try the demo, thanks.

Comment: @Reeza sorry I can’t upvote because I don’t have enough points.

Comment: I'm assuming the data sets are proprietary then, i.e. not available online?

Comment: The question has been asked and still remains open. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720306/importing-sas-cport-file-in-r

Comment: Hi, sorry but questions about finding a software or resource are off topic here.

Comment: And for reference: CPORT is _newer_ than XPORT.  XPORT is SAS's "open" format; CPORT is a closed format.  Read more [here](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000464.shtml).

Comment: @Reeza correct.

Comment: @pinegulf sorry, I did search but I didn’t find that question.

Comment: @Joe good point, my bad.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Reeza for people’s reference Stat/Transfer worked, and can do batch processing for multiple tables in one container file.